# Weird behavior when trying to update text in a GridView cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to prepend some text to what's already in a `GridView` cell in the `RowDataBound` event:

```
  protected void gvPatientSearch_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataRow dr = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(dr["Confidential"]))
            {
                String name = String.Copy(e.Row.Cells[1].Text);
                //the problem is the following line
                e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "<b><font color='red'>!</font></b>" + name;
            }
        }

    }
```

For some reason it seems that no matter what I do the original text is deleted. When I remove the line below the comment the name displays normally without the exclamation point; when I add the append code, for some reason the original text becomes a blank string and I only get the exclamation point. I have tried this with and without the `String.Copy` - I didn't think this would be needed but figured I would try it just in case. No luck.

I don't think this is relevant, but the first column in the row is a hidden column that contains a 1 or a 0. If the value is 1, I want to add the exclamation point. The data is there and this part is being called correctly, I just can't get the name to stay put.

Any ideas why this would be happening?

EDIT: Front end code below

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvPatientSearch" runat="server" Width="100%" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
                            PageSize="25" OnPageIndexChanging="gvPatientSearch_PageIndexChanging" OnSorting="gvPatientSearch_Sorting" OnRowDataBound="gvPatientSearch_RowDataBound"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="false" PagerSettings-Position="TopAndBottom" PagerStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" PagerSettings-Mode="NumericFirstLast" PagerSettings-PageButtonCount="5"
                            PagerSettings-FirstPageText=" First " PagerSettings-LastPageText=" Last " PagerSettings-PreviousPageText=" Previous " PagerSettings-NextPageText=" Next ">
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" />
                            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Confidential" DataField="Confidential" ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol"></asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="PatientName" DataNavigateUrlFields="PatientIdInternal" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="PatientProfile.aspx?InternalID={0}" HeaderText="Patient Name"
                                    SortExpression="PatientName" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="PatientID" HeaderText="Patient ID" SortExpression="PatientID" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="AccountNumber" HeaderText="Account Number" SortExpression="AccountNumber" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="DateOfBirth" HeaderText="Date Of Birth" SortExpression="DateOfBirth" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="PracticeName" HeaderText="Practice Name" SortExpression="PracticeName" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="PatientIdInternal" HeaderText="Internal ID" SortExpression="PatientIdInternal" Visible="false" />
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

I can see the values of all the other fields showing up correctly in Visual Studio at this part of the code, only the name field that I am trying to modify shows as an empty string.

Comment: Can you post the front-end relating to this? You cannot get the text from a cell on a RowDataBound event if the text is not in a control. Try making the text a label or a literal, and doing: `label myLabel = e.row.findcontrol("myLabel")`, `String name = myLabel.Text`

Comment: @TylerRoper see update

Comment: see my answer below, hopefully it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `HyperLinkField` is rendered as a Hyperlink control, and for this reason you cannot retrieve the cell's text directly. If you want the text, you must retrieve it from the *control*, not the *cell*:

```
HyperLink myLink = e.Row.Cells[1].Controls[0] as HyperLink;
String name = myLink.text;
```

An alternative would be to grab the name directly from the datasource by doing `DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "name")` in your code-behind.

Comment: Why am I able to see the other cells' string contents in the debugger? They are all BoundFields.

Comment: I guess it must be something to do with the HyperLinkField or something, that one is different from the others in several ways. Thanks for answering, I am just going to pull it straight from the data source.

Comment: @eddie_cat Correct. I believe I misspoke, please see my updated answer.

Comment: Yep, that works. For some reason I didn't look into the HyperLink, haha. THanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why that's happening, but I think you can work around it by applying you logic with a function like this:

```
public string Exclaim(bool confidential, string originalText)
{
    if (confidential) {
        return "<b><font color='red'>!</font></b>" + originalText;
    } else {
        return originalText;
    }
}
```

In your gridview, invoke the function using:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Exclaim(Eval("Confidential"), Eval("Name"))%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I think that would work.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and did it by changing the offending line to this:

```
e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "<b>font color='red'>!</font></b> " + Convert.ToString(dr["PatientName"]);
```

Still don't know why the other way doesn't work, if anyone else does and answers I will mark it correct.